# unique_ptr with deleter

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to use `std::unique_ptr` with deleter. This is my code:

```
template<class T>
struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(T* p) 
    {
        delete[] p;
    }
};

void Test()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<char>> v;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        char* p = new char[10];
        sprintf(p, "string %d", i);
        v.push_back( unique_ptr<char, Deleter<char>>(p) );  // error is here
    }
}
```

> error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(std::unique_ptr &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&'

Compiler: VC++ 2012. How can I fix this? My goal is to use `unique_ptr` with custom deleter which calls `delete[]` instead of default `delete`.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `vector<string>` or `vector<array<char>>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need, since `unique_ptr` knows about arrays already!

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> p(new char[10]);
sprintf(p.get(), "...");
```

The array specialization even gives you array-like access à la `p[0] = 'a';` etc.

Your vector type has to match, of course: `std:vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>>`

Answer (score 4):

`unique_ptr<char>` and `unique_ptr<char, Deleter<char>>` are two different types. Therefore, you should declare your vector as:

```
vector<unique_ptr<char, Deleter<char>>> v;
```